# android:screenOrientation="landscape" Scroll not working

Tags: android

how to scroll through activity when activity is in landscape mode,

Scenario: my textview has around thousand words and few buttons,how to apply scroll to this when activity is in landscape mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround your `TextView` with a `ScrollView`.

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
      android:text="lots of text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ScrollView>
```